# Symfony 3.4 Overblog Graphql dont understood how resolve query

Tags: php, symfony, graphql, symfony-3.4

I installed [GraphQLBundle](https://github.com/overblog/GraphQLBundle) on my existing Symfony 3.4 project and tried to create next type:

```
type RootQuery {
    post(limit: Int, offset: Int): [Post]
}

type Post {
        id: ID
        title(sort: String, search: String): String
        href: String
    }
```

Then I created ResolverMap:

```
<?php

class PostMap extends ResolverMap
{

    /**
     * @return array|callable[]
     */
    public function map()
    {
        return [
            'RootQuery' => [
                self::RESOLVE_FIELD => function ($value, Argument $argument, \ArrayObject $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
                    $limit = $argument['limit'] ?? 10;
                    $offset = $argument['offset'] ?? 0;

                    $paginator = new Paginator((int)$limit, (int)$offset);

                    return $this->getData($paginator);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

everything works pretty good, but I don't understood one moment:

```
{
  post(limit:10) {
    id
    title(sort: "ASC")
    href
  }
}
```

`limit` from post I can get, but parameters `sort` I can't get.

How can I resolve that query?

Comment: i dosnt think that your limit works fine... in your code yoou set fix limit to 10 if the param isnt set so you cant say now that works fine.. habe you tried that call with a other limit as 10 ? If yes then it works :)

Comment: @episch i try pther limit, and limit work fine. I dont understood how i can get data from subquery

Comment: maybe $argument['title']->sort, course title looks like an object

Comment: @episch nope. Not working.